# How to use tf.keras.backend.ctc_decode in a sequential model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, ocr

I am trying to create a offline handwriting recognition system. Since I am a beginner, I decided to try an recreate the model described in a [medium article by Harald Scheidl](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-a-handwritten-text-recognition-system-using-tensorflow-2326a3487cd5). The model framework is shown in the following image.

[image]

---

**My questions are as follows:

1. How do I use [CTC decode from keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/ctc_decode). I am using a sequential model with keras layers.
2. Will CTC loss be the loss function in the compile parameter?**

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you have a encoder-decoder model that outputs a probability distribution of a word being at position t being t in range [0, T). With this outputs, you can compose a sentence taking the word with highest probability at position t, this approach is called **greedy**. **Greedy** works well on classification task but for sentence generation the output may look a bit weird.
In the other hand, you can use a beam search. Beam search is pretty simple to understand (I link [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLWuzLLSIgw) a good resource to understand it), in few words we can say that beam search looks for the most probable output sequence S by computing the likelihood of the possible sequences by just multiplying the probabilities, and selecting the most probable: p(s) = p(0) * p(1) * ... * p(T).

The CTC loss is a bit special and in consequence has a custom output having also the extra  character to indicate that the position t is the same as the previous ones. With `ctd_decoder` from the keras API you can decode the CTC output sequence by either using a greedy or beam search approach.

Comment: I know how it works. I want to know how to implement it? To be more precise I want to know what code to write in order to include ctc_decode to the model.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great resource for understanding application of ctc_loss and ctc_decode

- https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/
- [https://docs.w3cub.com/tensorflow~python/tf/keras/backend/ctc_batch_cost](https://docs.w3cub.com/tensorflow%7Epython/tf/keras/backend/ctc_batch_cost)
- [https://docs.w3cub.com/tensorflow~python/tf/keras/backend/ctc_decode](https://docs.w3cub.com/tensorflow%7Epython/tf/keras/backend/ctc_decode)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

1)you use ctc decode through keras after model.predict

```
out = K.get_value(K.ctc_decode(prediction, 
input_length=np.ones(prediction.shape[0])*prediction.shape[1],
                 greedy=True)[0][0])
```

2)yes after defining custom ctc loss we call it in model.compile(loss='')

```
model.compile(loss={'ctc': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred}, optimizer = 
'adam')
```

*USING CTC IN MODEL ARCHITECTURE*
Suppose you have a model with folowing archi

```
inputs = Input(shape=(32,128,1))
#any number of conv and rnn layers
outputs = Dense(len(char_list)+1, activation = 'softmax')(blstm_2)

# model to be used at test time
act_model = Model(inputs, outputs)
```

now we define ctc loss and prepare the labels required for the ctc inputs, we call ctc loss by keras api

```
labels = Input(name='the_labels', shape=[max_label_len], dtype='float32')
input_length = Input(name='input_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')
label_length = Input(name='label_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')


def ctc_lambda_func(args):
   y_pred, labels, input_length, label_length = args

   return K.ctc_batch_cost(labels, y_pred, input_length, label_length)


loss_out = Lambda(ctc_lambda_func, output_shape=(1,), name='ctc') 
([outputs, labels, input_length, label_length])

#model to be used at training time
model = Model(inputs=[inputs, labels, input_length, label_length], 
outputs=loss_out)
```

now we compile it

```
model.compile(loss={'ctc': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred}, optimizer = 
'adam')
```

*USING CTC DECODER TO TEST TRAINED MODEL ON TEST SET*

```
# load the saved best model weights
act_model.load_weights('best_model30epoch.hdf5')

# predict outputs on validation images
prediction = act_model.predict(test_img[:15])

# use CTC decoder
out = K.get_value(K.ctc_decode(prediction, 
input_length=np.ones(prediction.shape[0])*prediction.shape[1],
                     greedy=True)[0][0])

# see the results
i = 0
for x in out:
   img = mpimg.imread(file_img[i])
   imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
   plt.show()
   print("original_text =  ", test_orig_txt[i])
   print("predicted text = ", end = '')
for p in x:  
    if int(p) != -1:
        print(char_list[int(p)], end = '')       
print('\n')
i+=1
```